# Why does my text box have weird padding?

Tags: html, css, wrapper, margin, padding

I can't figure out this code.

Here is my website: http://claireisabelwebb.com/

I've made wrappers around the main navigation to the left and to contain the photo and text to the right. I have two "boxes" in the text / photo container. Here is that code:

```
/* Wrapper for Text and Photo on Home Page */

.wrapper_text_photo{ 
        display:block;
        float: left;
        background: rgba(0,0,255, .8);
        width:800px;
        height: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-left:10px;
}

/* Photo on Home Page */

.photo_home {
        float: left;
        margin-right:10px;
}

/* Text on Home Page */

.home_text{ 
        display:block;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        width:800px;
        height: 400px;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="wrapper_text_photo">

<!-- Picture of Me __________________________________________-->

    <img class="photo_home" src="images/Home/claire-ed.jpg" alt="claire isabel webb" height="200px">

<!-- Text ___________________________________________________-->

    <div class="home_text">
            <p>I graduated in 2010 from Vassar College with departmental honors in astronomy. I also minored in philosophy and discovered a late interest in architecture and art history. ETC
            <br><br>
            Email me at claire.isabel.webb@gmail.com.
            <br> 
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the text box to align with the image, but no matter how much I play with the padding and margins, I can't seem to get it right.

THANK YOU !

Comment: I recommend using a reset stylesheet to equalize padding, positions etc. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this maybe it help

html

```
<div class="wrapper_text_photo">
    <div class="home_text">
            <p><img class="photo_home" src="images/Home/claire-ed.jpg" alt="claire isabel webb" height="200px" />I graduated in 2010 from Vassar College with departmental honors in astronomy. I also minored in philosophy and discovered a late interest in architecture and art history. ETC
            <br><br>
            Email me at claire.isabel.webb@gmail.com.
            <br> 
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.home_text p img {
    float:left;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/c7VA4/)

Answer (score 2):

The implicit margin on the paragraph is pushing `home_text` down. Remove its margins:

```
.home_text p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I just tried that, but still not working!

.home_text p{ 
        display:block;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        width:800px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0;
}

Comment: icktoofay is correct, he just added `<div class="home_text">` class before the `<p>` but you don't need to be more specific. Just add `margin: 0;` to the `p` selector (line 7 in styles.css)

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
p {
margin: 0;
}
```

Your "textbox" has 19px of top/bottom margin .. adding `margin: 0;` will set the top/right/bottom/left values to 0.

Comment: Sorry, where do you see this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want you want, one way to deal with it would be to move your image inside of the div containing your text:

```
<div class="wrapper_text_photo">
  <div class="home_text">
    <img class="photo_home" src="images/Home/claire-ed.jpg" alt="claire isabel webb" height="200px">
    <p>I graduated in 2010 from Vassar College with departmental honors in astronomy. I also minored in philosophy and discovered a late interest in architecture and art history. ETC
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

That would probably make one or the other of the `wrapper_text_photo` and `home_text` divs superfluous.